# Can I promote my own products here?

Tags: discussion

Can anybody tell me if a person is allowed promote (advertise) their own software to do with cooking on the site? I can't seem to find that answer.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Thank you for asking this question. Things can get confusing here, and it helps to know ahead of time what's expected.  Check out our [tour] and [help] for more explanation. We do hope you'll stay and contribute, or even just read the questions and answers. The information may even help you with your software project!

Answer (score 8):

There's a page in the [help center](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help) entirely about this: ["How not to be a spammer"](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/promotion)

Essentially, if mentioning a given product will genuinely help answer a question, then you may do so, but you must disclose your affiliation.

However, thinking of this site as a way to advertise is a really, really bad idea. It's a cooking Q&A site, and if you are here to do anything other than constructively answer questions, you're not in the right place, and things may go poorly for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.